# Frames html, I have a problem with them

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have 3 frames in my web, the upper frame have a searchbar, when I click the button "search" the text in the searchbar goes blank, I wanna that the searchbar, keep the text.
The text introduced in the search field, gives a url with the results of the query at the frames lower, don't use php because the query don't does in a server, only gives a text that is added to the URL with the results.

Comment: I think I speak for us all when I say "Huh?"

Comment: You need to add some meat to this question. Post your code. Explain to us, in detail, what you've tried so far. After all, none of us are getting paid, so make it easier for us.

Comment: Could you add all of your code to http://jsfiddle.net for example. You may not have to use frames at all.

Comment: Read the question thrice still not able to understand it :( whats the main moto here?

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, you have a page with three frames.  One of the frames contains a form, but when you submit the form, you want to load the results into a different frame.

I'm guessing your form is submitting to its own frame, which is why its going blank (because you're not using any PHP to refill the form with the POSTed value).

I'm very rusty with frames as I can't remember the last time I needed to use one, but my guess would be that you need a TARGET in your form that matches the ID or name of the frame you want to load the results into?

```
<form method='post' action='loadThisUrl.html' target='anotherFrame'>
  <input type='text' name='myfield' />
</form>
```